# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm currently experiencing an unhandled rejection error in my react/redux project and I'm a little confused as to why this is happening. I've been looking around for answers now for hours now with no success. This was working successfully before I tried to add in firebase (ref.push). I can post the working version code if needed. Originally I was just using db.json. Any help would be appreciated. I feel totally in over my head but I know this is gonna be something glaringly obvious to more experienced people.

create stream action (the error is throwing on line 2)

```
  export const createStream = (formValues) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { userId } = getState().auth;
    const response = await ref.push({ ...formValues, userId });
    console.log(response.data);
    dispatch({ type: CREATE_STREAM, payload: response.data});

    //Navigation to get user back to streams list
    history.push('/');
  };
};
```

reducers

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
      case FETCH_STREAMS:
        return {...state, ..._.mapKeys(action.payload, 'id')};
      case FETCH_STREAM:
        return {...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload};
      case CREATE_STREAM:
        return {...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload};
      case EDIT_STREAM:
        return {...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload};
      /* case DELETE_STREAM:
        return _.omit(state, action.payload); */
      default: 
        return state;
    }
  }
```

stack

```
eval
webpack-internal:///./src/reducers/streamReducer.js:24:326
combination
node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!/Users/seth/projects/twitchclone/client/node_modules/redux/es/redux.js:454
p
<anonymous>:1:36402
v
<anonymous>:1:36684
(anonymous function)
<anonymous>:1:40069
dispatch
node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!/Users/seth/projects/twitchclone/client/node_modules/redux/es/redux.js:213
e
<anonymous>:1:40553
eval
node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!/Users/seth/projects/twitchclone/client/node_modules/redux-thunk/es/index.js:12
dispatch
node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!/Users/seth/projects/twitchclone/client/node_modules/redux/es/redux.js:621
```

Comment: can you add log of action.payload in reducer?

Comment: console.log in reducer returns undefined

Comment: Can you add stack trace if available.

Comment: I think the error is coming from **action.payload.id** where action.payload is not an object as you are expecting.

Comment: what do you mean @yuvrajzohan

Comment: The error you see says you are trying to access property 'id' from an object. As I can see you are dispatching **CREATE_STREAM** action. And in CREATE_STREAM, you access the property **[action.payload.id]** which will lookup for **id** in your **action.payload** and if action has no payload then it is undefined. It's been a while I saw Redux code, so if you could put a **debugger** before **return** in CREATE_STREAM case and see what is the value of action.payload. Then we can proceed with what went wrong.

Comment: action.payload is undefined.

Comment: @SethJones, please provide a [MCVE] in https://codesandbox.io

Comment: @SethJones, So you found the bug. Now find out why the action has no payload. I'll have to look up documentation on redux to find out about action properties, but I want you to find out why it is **undefined**. It should be a single object if your code is correct in the question.

Comment: @yuvrajzohan I appreciate the time you've taken to guide me along without straight up giving me the answer. So I have a debugger before my dispatch. What exactly should I be looking for that would point me to my reasoning for undefined? When I step through the code it's just a lot of react internal code.

Comment: Is this your public project or something I can look into. If not. Check the value of **action**, just before **dispatch** check your **response.data** if it has an array or object. If it's array your **id** will be on object inside array. Proceed checking values from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your action creator, you seem to assume that the promise returned by `ref.push()` resolves to the pushed value. However, the [official API documentaion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) doesn't support this theory. It just says:

> **Returns**: non-null `firebase.database.ThenableReference`. Combined Promise and Reference; resolves when write is complete, but can be used immediately as the Reference to the child location.

So apparently, the promise is just for waiting for the operation to complete, and doesn't yield a value (i.e., always yields `undefined`).

As you know the value to return already before saving it to Firebase, you can restructure your code to return it directly.

```js
// Store stream before passing it to ref.push()
const stream = { ...formValues, userId };
await ref.push(stream);

// Pass the stream as action payload
dispatch({ type: CREATE_STREAM, payload: stream });
```